# Returning A Boolean Nested Inside A Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function nested inside a javascript plugin which quite simply checks if something exists inside of an IndexedDB and then ideally I want it to return true or false.

I have assigned the call to the function to a variable (eg var res = $(document).check('name');)

However all I get in the console output if I do a console debug on it is undefined. If I add more console logging into the function it is getting the record correctly and in the right part of the if statement but there is no value being returned.

```
(function($){
var db, tx, callback, options,
names = {
    checkFor: function(name){
      //Lightweight copy of above without Thumbs
      console.log('In checkfor');
      var tx = db.transaction('myDB').objectStore('people').get(name).onsuccess = function(event){
        console.debug('res',event);
        var res = event.target.result;
        if(res.length > 0)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      };
    }
 } 
$.extend($.fn,{
check: function(name){
  names.checkFor(name);
});
}(jQuery));
```

The above is an example, there are many more functions and the plugin is quite lengthily. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you can't return from a callback. if you have the data in the callback ok, just use it in the callback, you don't need to shove it somewhere else. async works by taking the action to the data (as opposed to taking the data to the action like top-down code does)

Comment: return a promise, or pass a function in to be exected within the callback

Comment: Im not using a callback for this function - i just purely wanted to return a true or false. How would i go about a promise?